# CXXMethodDecl::getNameAsString for template class constructor or destructor

Tags: c++, templates, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a small software in C++ with [libtooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) to translate C++ headers into  C++ skeleton files.

It works fine for non-template class but I'm having an issue with template classes, especially with template class's constructor or destructor.

I'm using `CXXMethodDecl::getNameAsString` to get the name of the function.
For a non template class like

```
  struct C
  {
    C();
    ~C();   
    //other stuff
  }
```

The previous function gives me (as I expect) `C` and `~C`.

But if the class is template like the following:

```
  template <class TT,int N> 
  struct C
  {
    C();
    ~C();
   }
```

I get as result : `C<TT, N>` and `~C<TT, N>`, which is not what I was expecting.
For me, the name of a function should not be dependent of the class being template. Classic functions behave the way I expect (same name in both cases).

Am I missing something ? Is this the normal behavior or a bug ?

Comment: Are you using libclang? The tags associated to you question hint that it's the [clang interface](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) you're using, but `CXXMethodDecl::getNameAsString` seems to be a C++ interface (and therefore incompatible with libclang's API).

Comment: I wanted to use the tag `libtooling` (because I'm using `libtooling`) but I could not (not enough reputation to create it !). So i used `libclang` instead, which was the closest thing to it.

Comment: OK. Maybe you should edit your question to mention it explicitly: it could increase your chance of getting an answer... As for libtooling, I personally don't know anything about it and can unfortunately not help you. Sorry.

Comment: `test(std::vector<int> m)` `CXXMethodDecl::getNameAsString` on `std::vector<int>` returns `vector` here.. 
Anyways I had a question for `libtooling`too, I created the tag !